# Do/While statements in Java

Tags: java, loops, do-while

Is there a way I can make a Do/While statement like this?

```
do {
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you wish to continue?");
} while (answer == yes);
```

Comment: Sorry if there is not enough information. I would post my code but my teachers check around to see if we stole some code off the internet.

Comment: Yes...just the way you are doing it but you will need to declare and initialize answer as int (just as Denis has suggested) before you step into your do/while loop (see JavaDocs for JOptionPane.showOptionDialog() method. On another note...if code is on the internet you don't steal it, you Copy and Use it.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I think you need to take a look at [Jeff Atwood's: Attribution Required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) post.  Copying without attribution or violation of whatever license the code is published under **is** potentially theft.

Comment: @zero298, Oh Dear...let me rephrase that... You don't steal it, you Copy and Use it and don't forget to through in the Attribution for it. :P

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `answer == yes`, you should check if it equals `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION` or `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` in your case.

Also, you should be having `int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you wish to continue?);`

Comment: The answer variable would be declared outside the do-while, so it would just be `answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You may change it to:

```
int answer = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
do {
    answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you wish to continue?");
} while (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
```